# Get define value in preprocessor time in c

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to create a define using macro expansion. The crated define shall hold the value of an other define. :)

Example:

```
#define ONE            1
#define TWO            2
#define MACRO(x, y)    ...
...
#define MACRO_1_2      3
```

My question is: how can I resolve / use the value of a define in macro expansion?

I have tried to use

```
#define TEST_MACRO_V2(x, y)      TEST_MACRO_V2_"x"_"y"
```

, but I get the following error:

> main.c:18:34: error: ‘TEST_MACRO_V2_’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>    #define TEST_MACRO_V2(x, y)      TEST_MACRO_V2_"x"_"y"

My test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE   1
#define TWO   2

#define TEST_MACRO_V1(x, y)      TEST_MACRO_V1_##x##_##y
#define TEST_MACRO_V1_ONE_TWO    3

//#define TEST_MACRO_V2(x, y)    TEST_MACRO_V2_##('x')##_##('y')  -> this version does not work
#define TEST_MACRO_V2(x, y)      TEST_MACRO_V2_"x"_"y"
#define TEST_MACRO_V2_1_2        4

int main()
{
    printf("Test Macro V1: %d\n", TEST_MACRO_V1(ONE, TWO));
    printf("Test Macro V2: %d\n", TEST_MACRO_V2(ONE, TWO));

    return 0;
}
```

> Note: TEST_MACRO_V1 works fine. I need TEST_MACRO_V2.

Comment: What do you need to do with V2 that you can't do with V1?

Comment: :) The solution shall be independent from the name of macro argument. It means, the user can use other define name, but this defines have always the same value, like 0,1,2 …
So, in the “end define” I need the values of the defines used in the macro call.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please post exactly what the expected expansion of `TEST_MACRO_V2(ONE, TWO)` should be, or what the expected output is of the program you posted

Comment: Also explain what is the point of `MACRO_1_2` , `TEST_MACRO_V1_ONE_TWO` and `TEST_MACRO_V2_1_2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on ideone.com:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE   1
#define TWO   2

#define TEST_MACRO_HELPER(x, y) TEST_MACRO_##x##_##y
#define TEST_MACRO(x, y)        TEST_MACRO_HELPER(x, y)
#define TEST_MACRO_1_2          4

int main()
{
    printf("Test Macro: %d\n", TEST_MACRO(ONE, TWO));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test Macro: 4
```